# pausing for loop of a data stream for further manipulation

Tags: python, pandas

have the following code resulting in a streaming data frame with over 5000 rows every minute. As this data frame is within a for loop am unable to manipulate the data within the data frame. So I need to know how to segregate the data frame to come be out of the for loop, say every 5 minute and then restart again to collect the information in the data frame.
'''

```
 df=pd.DataFrame(data=None)


def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
global df
for sc in ticks:
    token=sc['instrument_token']
    name=trd_portfolio[token]['name']
    ltp=sc['last_price']
    df1=pd.DataFrame([name,ltp]).T
    df1.columns=['name','ltp']
    df=df.append(df1,ignore_index=True)

    print(df)
```

'''
Resultant output is

```
           name     ltp
0          GLAXO  1352.2
1           GSPL  195.75
2           ABAN      18
3     ADANIPOWER    36.2
4        CGPOWER       6
...          ...     ...
1470      COLPAL    1317
1471         ITC   196.2
1472    JUBLFOOD  1698.5
1473     HCLTECH   550.6
1474      INDIGO   964.8

[1475 rows x 2 columns]
```

further manipulation required on the data frame are like:
'''

```
df['change']=df.groupby('name')['ltp'].pct_change()*100
g = df.groupby('name')['change']
counts = g.agg(
pos_count=lambda s: s.gt(0).sum(),
neg_count=lambda s: s.lt(0).sum(),
net_count=lambda s: s.gt(0).sum()- s.lt(0).sum()).astype(int)
print(counts)
```

'''

However, am unable to freeze the for loop for a certain time for other processes to happen.  I did try the sleep method, but it sleeps for given time and then goes back to the for loop.

Need guidance on how we can freeze the for loop for certain time so that the other codes can be executed and gain going back to the for loop to continue collecting the data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pausing of the loop but you can just pass the arguments to some other function that performs the other operations after every n iterations.The sudo code would be something like.

```
for loop in range(10000):
    data        #collecting data
    if loop==100:
        other_operation(data):

def other_operation(data):
    #perform other operations here
```

This willperform the other manipulations after every 100 loop iterations.

Comment: hi is async function capable of doing it. am not sure how it works